# Verilog addition unexpectedly results in x

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

The output of this executable is x until you remove d from the c assignment. The output is x x x x. When d is removed from the assignment, the output is as expected "2 3 4 5".

```
module test();
  logic [1:0] a, b, d;
  logic [2:0] c;
  assign c = a+b+d;
  initial begin
    d = 0;
    a = 1;
    b = 1;
    $display(c);
    a = 2;
    b = 1;
    $display(c);
    a = 2;
    b = 2;
    $display(c);
    a = 2;
    b = 3;
    d = 3;
    $display(c);
  end

endmodule
```

Comment: Max possible value is 9, which doesn't fit in c. But I'm not sure it explains anything...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both outputs are valid, you have a race condition.

A continuous `assign` statement is a concurrent process that waits for signals on the RHS to change, then evaluates the expression and makes the assignment.

The `initial` block is another concurrent process. As you procedurally make assignments to each signal, the scheduler is free to jump to to the other process and execute it, ... or it can continue executing statements until hitting a blocking delay, or it terminates.

If fact, many tools *in-line* continuous assignments as an optimization, only executing them when the lhs gets referenced. That could be what's happening here when you remove d from the rhs.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in understanding verilog simulation. It is an event-driven flow.

In your case assignment to 'c' happens when any input to the *assign* statement change.
But the change will be detected only when execution of the non-timed chunk in your initial block is done. And this chunk ended with the last statement.

So, as a result, all your $display(c) will show the value of 'c' as it existed before the initial block starts execution. In order to see updates, you need let the code wait till the changes have a chance to propagate. A simple example would be the following:

```
initial begin
  d = 0;
  a = 1;
  b = 1;
  #1 $display(c);
  a = 2;
  b = 1;
  #1 $display(c);
  a = 2;
  b = 2;
  #1 $display(c);
  a = 2;
  b = 3;
  d = 3;
  #1 $display(c);
end
```

Adding #1 before every $display will let the changes to propagate and display expected results.

There is a gray area in interpretation of the code like yours. Note that the initial block has a, b, and d as the output. In the sequential code with no timing control constructs it just re-assigns the values of those outputs. For simulation semantics only the lastly assigned values matter and should trigger an event.  However, it looks like some simulators might interpret it differently and trigger events whenever the value changes. This is up to the simulator implementation in this case. For example, as i noticed, VCS does trigger events for every change, but only in some cases. NC does not trigger those events.

I guess you can interpret the simulation behavior as `undefined` for this kinds of the code. To make it deterministic, use correct timing controls, as in the example above.

Comment: that doesn't explain why removing d from the assign statement gives non-x output

Comment: which assignment  do you remove exactly?

Comment: replace
assign c = a + b + d;
with
assign c = a + b;

Comment: Ok, this is a result of optimization done by *some* simulators. VCS does it, NC does not. The latter still has 'x' in all cases. The point is that the only values which matter are at the beginning of the next simulation cycle.  VCS creates glitches (probably due to its interpretation of $display).  But at the beginning of the next cycle both have the same value of '5'.